# Why are all of the other parts of an animation moving together except for one?

Tags: animation, keyframes

For some reason, the parts to this object all move to one spot together- except for the plus and minus. Any ideas why?

Keyframe 1:
[image]

Somewhere in between frames:
[image]

And the final keyframe works fine. Why is the object doing this and how do I fix it?

Origin Points:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: maybe check your origin points...

Comment: @moonboots added

Comment: @Chris all of them are at the bottom of each shape except for the plus/minus. do you suspect that is the reason for the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have given some rotation keyframes to your objects but their origin is not located at the same location, so the objects won't rotate together, they will shift from each other. You have several solutions, like joining all your objects, or parenting the small ones to the big one and only keep the action of the big one, or parent all the objects to an empty and animate the empty...